# VB.NET Installer Package using Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, installation, visual-studio-2015, installation-package, vs-community-edition

I have created a VB.NET project using **Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition**. I can't figure out how to obtain the ***Installer (Setup) Package***. I want to create this setup (**Commune.exe**) so that users can install on their computers. After installation, the program should appear in Start Menu and in Control Panel too. I would be happy to give the program a custom name (**MDC Solutions**) such that it will appear in the control panel as developed by MDC Solutions. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all install this.left

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9

Once you have this installed,

go to Solution Explorer and right click "Solution "YOUR PROGRAMS NAME"
go down to "Add" and select "New Project"
on the right hand side scroll down to "Other Project Type" and expend it and click on "Visual Studio Installer" and select "Setup Project" and Name your setup exe.

A new window will pop up.
On the left hand side you will see "Application Folder"
Right click on it and select "Add" > "Project output"
and click on "Primary Output" and press "ok"

Once you have done that, on the right hand side you should see two or more files, right click on the one that should say "Primary output From "YOUR PROGRAMS NAME"
and select "create Shortcut - "YOUR PROGRAMS NAME"

Once that is done, rename your shortcut to your programs name. eg "my first program" after that click and drag it to "Users Desktop Folder on the left hand side.

Then right click "User's Program Menu" and add a Folder and name it to your programs company name "eg Microsoft" this will make a folder in the start menu.

After that select the folder you have just renamed and right click on the right hand side and select "Create new Shortcut" a window will pop up for you,
select the "Application Folder" and then "Primary output from YOUR PROGRAMS NAME" and press "ok"

Once all of this is done close out of it and go to "Solution Explorer" and press F4, here you will have the options to add details about your program eg who it is and even an icon.

I may have missed somethings, but after reading this you will have a basic idea of what is required and you will be able to add your own things.

Also i cant remember but you might have to also add your programs Icon to the "Application Folder"

once you have done everything, open "solution explorer" and right click on the new project you have created and press "build" you will be able to find the files where you main project is located.

Good Luck!

Comment: But for the 5th paragraph where you ask that  "Create new shortcut" ... and onwards, I don't find any ok button to press. In the Solution Explorer, I can see the Setup File but I can't see it in the bin or release folder of my Project. The build/rebuild of the project gives error messages such as invalid or unspecified folder for shortcut "This Project".  I marked answer correct because I think you've put me half-way through. Good enough to fight for the rest. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks mate, you should be able to create a new shortcut, name your shortcut eg notepad, and then press the ok button.

What are the errors that you are getting when trying to build?

in the Solution explorer there should be your setup file that you can expand.
Let me know if you have any trouble with it and i will be happy to help you.
Happy Coding :)

Comment: It worked perfectly and I have my setups (.exe and .msi) now. In the Control Panel however, the company name still shows **Default Company Name**. i couldn't get an icon for the application. I will try hard and get over that soon. Thanks for your support.

Comment: press F4 when the solution explorer is open and it will have the option in there to change the name of the company and well as set a change icon

Comment: I should have added that I pressed the F4 key when the Solution Explorer was open and I made the changes. Unless afterwards, I should press another key or button to complete the process.

Comment: make sure that the setup packed is the one that is highlight being pressing F4